# State and explain whether the exchange particle is a $W^{+}$ , $W^{-}$ or $Z^{0}$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics

[image: state and explain whether the exchange particle is a W+ , W- or Z^0]

> State and explain whether the exchange particle is a $W^{+}$ , $W^{-}$ or $Z^{0}$.

I think it is $W^{-}$ but I can't explain in detail please help me.

Comment: $u$ is certainly not decaying to $\bar{u}$. Rather, $s$ is decaying to $u$ and producing $d$, and $\bar{u}$ in the process. Your explanation is invalid simply because it does not at all describe the process which is actually occurring. I suggest you think about what must happen with regards to charge, when you go from $s$ to $u$. That should help you in answering your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider charge. It must be conserved from our $Y$ particle to the $\bar{u}d$.

Charges:
$$\bar{u} = -\frac{2}{3}$$
$$d = -\frac{1}{3}$$

(anti particles have the opposite sign charge).

So now we have an end state of $-\frac{2}{3}-\frac{1}{3}=-1$. Which of your potential particles ($W^{+},W^{-},Z^{0}$) does this agree with?